# How to an update opentok latest version in old projects without support Androidx?Is it possible?

Tags: android, opentok

I am using opentok version `compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.13.0'` and i want to upgrade to `compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.16.1'` but it's said it's necessary to whole project convert into AndroidX.Does it possible it without support AndroidX Please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenTok 2.16.1 does not require your project to be built with AndroidX support.

What you need to do is to use Java8 by adding this to your project:

```
android {
  ...
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```